# One Link to Rule Them All: iphone/Android single url redirect to app if available else web

Tags: android, iphone, email, url, schema

I would like to send out emails to my users, and ideally we have 1 link in the email for an action to be performed. Ex: (View Item).

So if the user clicked this link and they where on their iphone it should open the app and go to a certain location.

But that same url should be able to open the android if thats the device being used. And if no devices are being used then it should take you to the web.

I know I can have a single url that when clicked does a redirect based upon client type, but by the time the redirect is happening, will that still trigger what needs to be triggered via a mobile device to open the App rather than just redirect to the user to some webpage that (being a mobile url schema) doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP browser may send an `User-Agent` header with information about the browser, OS, etc. Note that some browser may fake these values.

Comment: I'm not really looking for how to detect browser/device. That i can do. What i need to know is if there is a way to have a server side redirect affect the app that is opened.

Comment: From the server, you can use [HTTP status codes][1] (look at the 3xx codes) to send a redirect. Of course, it depends on the device handling it and non blocking it due to security issues. [1]: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html